# Display of latest post from all categories in a wordpress template

Tags: wordpress

I am using a custom taxonomy named coupon in my website.
Also I had nearly 10 categories in the taxonomy.
Is there any way to display a single post from each categories?

Now I am able to display all the posts from each category.
But I need to display the latest posts from each category (latest one post).

Comment: Have you tried this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Yeah, I used the same, but only able to display the posts by number. For eg., if I give the 'posts_per_page' = 5, then only 5 posts get displayed. I need to display the latest added posts from each custom category.

Answer (score 0):

Do a seperate query for each taxonomy and limit the results to 1 (posts_per_page=1).

Comment: Could you please elaborate the process?

Comment: Could you make your question a bit more clear? How are you displaying the posts? Are you using a WP_Query object? Are you using the taxonomy URLs?

Comment: I am using the WP_Query object. Now it displays all the posts from the each category, this looks not good. I need to display only the latest posts added to each category.

Comment: As an argument for WP_Query add posts_per_page=1